# Why is transfer from test to production of Asp.Net-Core app completely not working

Tags: asp.net-core, nopcommerce

We've been finalizing NopCommerce .Net Core web app which has been running great on a test server.  I'm now trying to transfer the app to our production server, which did not  have .Net Core.  I installed the latest .Net Core hosting bundle and rebooted the server.  I also have Web Deploy running on both the host and the client.  I exported the app from the test machine and imported it into a newly created IIS site.  After setting up the bindings - and enabling stdoutlogging, I try to see what's working, and get indication that "An error occurred while starting the application".  No indication what the error is.  Logs is not being written to.  The event viewer tells me that:
Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/NOPCOMMERCE' started process '6980' successfully and is listening on port '41573', which is a random port not binded to.

One interesting thing I noticed on the test server is a "user" called nopCommerce which has full rights to the nopCommerce folder in inetpub/wwwroot.  However this user does not show when I look at local users and groups.  I am not sure therefore what this "user" is and if/how I should create it.  Based on some advice from somewhere I temporarily gave everyone full rights to the nopCommerce folder, but that didn't work either.

Can anybody please aim me in the right direction?

Comment: Does a small "Hello world" website deployment work?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry, got pulled off on another project.  Hello World works fine.  Server seems to have all the bits.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was a bad setup - access rights to subfolders of nopCommerce was one, which I solved by giving the users group modify rights.  This might be a bad idea and I will do some more research.  The other fault was a bad database login in the connectionString.

Ultimately I had to learn that instead of starting the app via IIS, it can be run from the command-line, and then messages and errors will be displayed in the DOS box.  What to run is determined from the

I still don't know where the nopCommerce user comes from on the staging server.